# How to resize django ckeditor inside the form model

Tags: django, ckeditor

I need to use `django-ckeditor` in various part of my project, so for each part need to resize it.

But I know that I can resize it by adding this definitions in settings as below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
]

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
         'height': 70,
         'width': 430,
    },
}
```

however, as I mentioned above, I am using several editor in different parts, so need to resize them differently.

How to reside in different `form.fields`?

```
class proForm(forms.ModelForm):

    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        fields = ('__all__')
```

This raises error:

```
description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget({
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
         'height': 70,
         'width': 430,
    }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor

It seems you can define multiple set of editors and give *config_name* when instantiating the field.